# Angular 2 RC6 form: can't show valid div

Tags: forms, angular

In my angular 2 RC6 project, I have a very simple template-driven form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm">
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="username" name="username" #username="ngModel" ngModel required>
 <div *ngIf="!username.valid && username.touched" class="alert alert-danger"> Username is required</div>
<div *ngIf="!_isValidUser" class="alert alert-danger">Invalid username </div>
</form>

onSubmit(form: NgForm): void {
     code for checking if it is a valid user
     if it is a valid user ---> close the form
     if it is not a valid user --> reset the form: form.reset()
}
```

In component, I have code to check if it is a valid user in onSubmit() function.

However, the above alert-danger div div will never show up except I manually trigger/click the input box.

Does any one know why?

Comment: And when exactly do you want it to show? By using username.touched you require it to be modified before it can show.

Comment: @rook - sorry, I missed some code, and now is it added. I want the require warning div show only when the user filled out some info but actually deleted all of them, I don't want to show it when the form rendered the first time. What's why I put username.touched there.
And for invalid username warning div, I don't want it show until the user click submit button. But now, I have the same issue with the two div, they can't show until the user click the input box and trigger it.

Comment: For the submit part I'm afraid you will need to do it yourself. As far as I know Angular validates inputs on change, so you will have to add your own validation code to the submit method.

As for required - I still don't understand what you need. Looking at your code it should show the message when the field had focus or something was entered and than deleted.